# Replace single quote by two single quotes in a file with batch powershell command

Tags: powershell, single-quotes

I'm currently working on an automated setup program. It has to execute SQL command. I decided to create it with a simple batch file which allows me to use commands like sqlcmd or Powershell.

I'm working on a XML file that will get insert into another file. First, I have to replace some strings in it. I successfully used the -replace command like that :

```
powershell -Command "(gc source_file.xml) -replace 'utf-8', 'utf-16' | sc updated_file.xml"
```

Now, the updated_file.xml still contains single quotes that I'd like to replace by '' (two single quotes). I'd like to use the replace command again to make the substitution. I tried to escape the single quote character but it didn't work :

```
powershell -Command "(gc source_file.xml) -replace "`'", "`'`'" | sc updated_file.xml"
```

The error shows that the single quote isn't escaped. What's more, in my case, it seems that the replace command only reads string between single quotes. I also tried with a regex::Escape("`'") without success.

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: try something like this:
    -replace "$([char]39)", "$([char]39)$([char]39)"

Comment: Do yourself a favor -- as soon as complex quoting issues like this crop up, where you have to figure out how to quote things in such a way that both `cmd` and PowerShell are happy, switch to explicit scripts or use `-EncodedCommand`. *Within* PowerShell, `-replace "'", "''"` works fine with no further need for escaping.

Comment: powershell -Command "(gc source_file.xml)  -replace 'utf-8', 'utf-16' -replace '''', '''''' | sc updated_file.xml"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
powershell -Command "(gc source_file.xml)  -replace 'utf-8', 'utf-16' -replace '''', '''''' | sc updated_file.xml"
```

Answer (score 1):

For cmd.exe you have to escape inner double quotes with a backslash, so this should work:

```
powershell -NoP -C "(gc source_file.xml) -replace 'utf-8','utf-16' -replace \"'\",\"''\" | Set-Content updated_file.xml"
```

Hint: the alias sc is removed in upcoming releases of PowerShell, so avoid it.
Also changing content text utf8 => utf-16 won't change the encoding (possibly append `-Encoding UTF8` to the gc.